# Is it normal for an exhaust fan cover to hang below the finished ceiling?

Tags: bathroom, ceiling

I live in an apt complex and have asked my live-in manager to please fix the bathroom fan. He tells me that there is "nothing to fix". Can someone please tell me if this is true?

[image: bathroom fan]

Answer (score 6):

This is not normal. The trim plate should be tight against the finished ceiling.

[image]

You might be able to simply push the trim plate up, where it will lock into place. If that doesn't work, you'll have to adjust the retaining clips to hold the plate in place.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue a few times with bathroom fans.  I have no idea why the manufacturers don't just let us screw the fans in.  The retaining clips are crap, sometimes don't hold well and often are never snug when they do.  Yours is really bad so I am thinking it is not in the right spot.  You usually have to hold the clips together and push up.

A first option is to cut off part of the retaining clip and try again.  But more often than not when I have this issue I simply drill a small hole on opposite side of cover and screw them into the ceiling (use a drywall anchor).  These are really light and the screws are much easier to deal with than the clips.

Answer (score 0):

Could also be that the frame is installed above the finished ceiling so clips aren't able to get above the wide spot where they lock. Drop the level of the exhaust fan